# Propriedade Clip

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estou utilizando o propriedade `clip` em uma tag  para fazer um recorte no bottom da mesma, porém essa imagem será dinâmica, o tamanho do width é fixo mas o tamanho do height vai se dinamótico.

Sendo assim se eu tiver uma imagem com `height: 1000px;` e a propriedade `clip-path: inset(0px 0px 10px 0px);`  vai recorta 10px do bottom da imagem.

Mas eu preciso fazer um corte de 100% do bottom da imagem caso  o height for maior que 542px.

Não importando o tamanho do height a imagem sempre vai fica com o tamanho de 542px devido ao recorte.

*Pois se eu determinar um tamanho fixo com CSS na imagem ela acaba ficando achatada.*

Comment: Coloque `object-fit:cover` no estilo da tag img, assim vc pode definir o tamanho e a imagem não fica achatada. Essa propriedade meio que faz a `img` se comportar como um `background-image` ai vc pode por o heig que ela não achata. Se resolver seu problema me fala que eu faço uma resposta com mais detalhes

Comment: @hugocsl sem sucesso.

Comment: Cara coloca seu código ai HTML/CSS para podemos simular esse problema. Só com o relato não da para ajudar muito mais...

Comment: @hugocsl, engano na falha, digitei a propriedade errado, deu certo utilizando object-fit:cover. Obrigado <3

Comment: Eduardo fiz uma resposta um pouco mais completo com fonte e link de referência, assim vc pode deixar como resolvida se ela resolveu seu problema. Assim não fica constando como pergunta aberta não resolvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o seu relato vc pode usar a propriedade `object-fit:cover` para contornar o problema do achatamento da imagem. Como dito no comentário ela evita que a imagem se achate, pois ela vai se comportar como um `background-imagem`.

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor. Repare que a imagem tem 400px de largura, mas com o `object-fit:cover` ela não fica achatada.

```css
body {display:flex}
img.fit {
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<h2>SEM object-fit</h2>
<img src="https://placecage.com/401/201" alt="Paris" width="200" height="300">

<h2>COM object-fit</h2>
<img class="fit" src="https://placecage.com/401/201" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
```

Documentação básica com exemplos práticos de uso https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp